# Having a Visualforce page inside of a standard page results in duplicate main.js

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, standard-objects, performance

I have a custom Visualforce page rendered inside of a standard page Opportunity in one of my layouts.  I was researching some performance issues when I noticed that 2 main.js files are travelling down to the browser.  And both files are identical.  Looks like one is coming with the main Opportunity page and the other one comes from the embedded Visualforce page.

Seeing how main.js is around 800kb, I'd rather it came down just once.

Is there a way to prevent SF from sending 2 copies of the same file?

Comment: I assume one reason for the two copies is that the layout UI and Visualforce UI is served from different domains and so the JavaScript has to be too (because of [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restrictions). So extra time the first time the page is loaded, but presumably both copies cached by the browser after that.